# LG webOS CLI: InvalidAsn1Error: encoding too long

Tags: command-line-interface, television, webos, lg

I get this error when I trying to connect to my tv with webOS TV CLI:

```
C:\webOS_TV_SDK\CLI>ares-install --device tv --list
ares-install ERR! uncaughtException InvalidAsn1Error: encoding too long
```

In the webOS IDE I get:
Please check the device "tv" authentication credentials.

Anyone know what the error can be and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue can happen when you have the wrong ssh private key associated with the device, or no ssh key at all. In the Developer Mode app, start the key server. Using CLI tools, run (replace `<device name>` by actual device name):

```
ares-novacom --device <device name> --getkey
```

There will be a command prompt to enter Passphrase. Enter the exact characters (case sensitive) as displayed on the TV screen in the Dev app. The passphrase consists of 6 characters and is shown in the bottom left side of the Developer Mode app screen.

Comment: Thanks for this, the case sensitivity was the issue for me, decided to be lazy this one time as I figured it wouldn't matter but it definitely does!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem when i created the connection from the command line. Using the WebOS IDE i was able to create a succesful connection. Steps can be found on: http://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/app-test/#connectingTVandPC